# Update div content when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css, onclick

I'm trying to create a list of links that update the content in a div when clicked.

Looking at the code below, I want the div with id `container` to be populated with the content of the relevant div when a link is clicked.

```
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" onclick="fixScroll('food');"></a>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" onclick="fixScroll('water');"></a>

<div id="food"  style="height:20px;">Clicking Food Link Shows this in Div</div>
<div id="water"  style="height:20px;">Clicking Water Link Shows this in Div</div>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:150px;">This Div box is Empty till you click one the links, then its Populated by the correct stuff</div>
```

I hope this is enough information. I'm basically trying to make the content of hidden divs (`food` & `water`) display in the `container` div when clicking a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should work.

```js
function fixScroll(id) {
  var text = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = text;
}
```

```html
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" onclick="fixScroll('food');">Food</a>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery" onclick="fixScroll('water');">Water</a>

<div id="food"  style="display: none; height:20px;">Clicking Food Link Shows this in Div</div>
<div id="water"  style="display: none; height:20px;">Clicking Water Link Shows this in Div</div>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:150px;">This Div box is Empty till you click one the links, then its Populated by the correct stuff</div>
```

Comment: where that `display:none;` comes

Comment: The "display: none;" will "collapse" the food and water divs.

Comment: Thanks for this. This is exactly what i was trying to explain and figure out. Thanks to everyone's fast replies!

Answer (score 0):

Edited to use pure JS without jQuery:

```js
var btn = document.querySelectorAll('.classNameYouLike');
for (var i in btn) {
 btn[i].onclick = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('#container').innerHTML = document.querySelector(e.target.getAttribute('data-source')).innerHTML;
 };
}
```

```html
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery classNameYouLike" data-source="#food">food</a>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery classNameYouLike" data-source="#water">water</a>

<div id="food"  style="display:none;">Clicking Food Link Shows this in Div</div>
<div id="water"  style="display:none;">Clicking Water Link Shows this in Div</div>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:150px;">This Div box is Empty till you click one the links, then its Populated by the correct stuff</div>
```

Original jQuery-powered solution:

```js
$('.classNameYouLike').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#container').html($($(this).data('source')).html());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery classNameYouLike" data-source="#food">food</a>
<a class="glyphicon glyphicon-cutlery classNameYouLike" data-source="#water">water</a>

<div id="food"  style="display:none;">Clicking Food Link Shows this in Div</div>
<div id="water"  style="display:none;">Clicking Water Link Shows this in Div</div>

<div id="container" style="width:100%; height:150px;">This Div box is Empty till you click one the links, then its Populated by the correct stuff</div>
```

Comment: Please write the code in pure JS since he did not ask for a JQuery example.

Comment: I would appreciate it if you would remove the negative mark now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple, you can add this below your other HTML (as the last element inside your body element):

```
<script>
  const container = document.querySelector("#container");

  function food(){ 
    const foodText = document.querySelector("#food").innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML = foodText;
  }

  function water(){ 
    const waterText = document.querySelector("#water").innerHTML;
    container.innerHTML = waterText;
  }
</script>
```

You can improve on this by
1) putting the script in an external file and referencing it from your page, and/or
2) combining the two functions into one by giving it a parameter name (like `myText`) inside the parentheses, and using that parameter in place of `foodText` inside the function. Then when you call the function, instead of just saying `food()`, you would say `myCombinedFunctionName(foodText)`.

Comment: Check out my answer to minimize the amount of functions.